# In Bash, how can I tell if I am currently in a terminal

Tags: bash, gnome

I want to create my own personal logfile that logs not only when I log in and out, but also when I lock/unlock my screen. Kindof like /var/log/wtmp on steroids.

To do this, I decided to run a script when I log into Ubuntu that runs in the background until I quit. My plan to do this is to add the script to `.bashrc`, using `./startlogging.sh &` and in the script I will use `trap` to catch signals. That's great, except `.bashrc` gets run every time I open a new terminal, which is not what I want for the logger.

Is there a way to tell in Bash that the current login is a gnome login? Alternatively, is there some sort of `.gnomerc` I can use to run my script?

**Edit:** Here is my script:

**Edit 2:** Removed the script, since it's not related to the question. I will repost my other question, rather than repurpose this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to detect what type of terminal it is?

Try:

```
echo $TERM
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

> TERM (Unix-like) - specifies the type of computer terminal or terminal
>   emulator being used (e.g., vt100 or dumb).

See also: [List of Terminal Emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators)

Comment: Do you know what the `$TERM` would be when I first log into gnome?

Comment: @RobertMartin it should be `gnome-terminal` for gnome.

Comment: Edit: Your answer is the answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: For posterity, I see $TERM="dumb" when I log into gnome.

Answer (score 0):

for bash use :  ~/.bash_logout

that will get executed when you logout, which sounds like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not really sufficient. I want my script to run like a daemon, logging when I log in, lock/unlock screen, and log out. See the script in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for just bash, what you want are `.bash_login`/`.bash_logout` in your home directory (rather than `.bashrc`)  These are run whenever a LOGIN shell starts/finishes, which happens any time you log in to a shell (on a tty or console, or via ssh or other network login).  These are NOT run for bash processes created to run in terminal windows that you create (as those are not login shells) so won't get run any time you open a new terminal.

The problem is that if you log in with some mechanism that does not involve a terminal (such as gdm running on the console to start a gnome or kde or unity session), then there's no login shell so .bash_login/logout never get run.   For that case, the easiest is probably to put something in your `.xsessionrc`, which will get run every time you start an X session (which happens for any of those GUI environments, regardless of which one you run).  Unfortunately, there's no standard script that runs when an X session finishes.

Comment: This seems promising. If I put my script in `.xsessionrc` and background it using &, will it terminate immediately? Will it become a daemon? I want it to quit when I logout (receive a SIGHUP). As you can see from the script, it wants to run as a daemon.